# Function Composition with RealFrac and Floating Int

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to compose 3 functions.

```
ghci> let f = floor . (logBase 2) . length
```

However, I don't understand this compile-time error.

```
<interactive>:47:9:
    No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of `floor'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Int)
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `floor'
    In the expression: floor . (logBase 2) . length
    In an equation for `f': f = floor . (logBase 2) . length

<interactive>:47:18:
    No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of `logBase'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Int)
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `(logBase 2)'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `(logBase 2) . length'
    In the expression: floor . (logBase 2) . length
```

In this output:

```
    No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of `floor'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Int)
```

Does that mean I need to explicitly specify the type (via `:: some_type_here`) rather than rely on Haskell to infer the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the type of `logbase` is:

```
λ> :t logbase
logBase :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
```

So, they accept type which are instances of `Floating` typeclass ie. `Float` and `Double` data type. So if you do proper type conversion, it should work:

```
λ> let f = floor . (logBase 2) . fromIntegral . length
```